# Can't leave editing mode on prime faces roweditor

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I have this code that shows a table with a prime faces datatable and a roweditor column. When I click on pencil icon, editable mode is enabled but after that, when I click on check or cancel icon nothing happens, editable mode remains active. I've search a lot about it but I couldn't find response. Listener on backing bean is not called.

This is my code of the view:

```
<p:dataTable var="vac" value="#{vacDocBean.obl}" id="documentacion" editable="true"> 
    <f:facet name="header">  
      Table
    </f:facet>  

    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" update="@this" listener="#{vacDocBean.onEditRow(_record)}" />

    <p:column headerText="Edad">#{vacuna.inm.e}</p:column> 
    <p:column headerText="Inm">#{vac.inm.n}</p:column>       


   <p:column headerText="Fecha aplicacion">  
    <p:cellEditor>  
            <f:facet name="output">  
               <h:outputText value="#{vac.fechaAplicacion}">  
                     <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>  
                </h:outputText>  
            </f:facet>  
            <f:facet name="input"> 
                 <p:calendar value="#{vac.fechaAplicacion}" style="width:100%"/>  
            </f:facet>  
        </p:cellEditor>  
   </p:column> 
   <p:column headerText="Marca">  
    <p:cellEditor>  
            <f:facet name="output">  
                <h:outputText value="#{vac.marca}" />  
            </f:facet>  
            <f:facet name="input">  
                <p:inputText value="#{vac.marca}" style="width:100%"/>  
            </f:facet>  
        </p:cellEditor>  
   </p:column> 
   <p:column headerText="Lote">  
    <p:cellEditor>  
            <f:facet name="output">  
                <h:outputText value="#{vac.lote}" />  
            </f:facet>  
            <f:facet name="input">  
                <p:inputText value="#{vac.lote}" style="width:100%"/>  
            </f:facet>  
        </p:cellEditor>  
   </p:column> 
    <p:column headerText="Editar" styleClass="ui-editable-column-options">  
      <!--  <p:commandLink  ajax="true">-->
              <p:rowEditor  />
      <!--  </p:commandLink >     -->   
    </p:column>  
     <f:facet name="footer">  
         Vacunación documentada
    </f:facet> 

</p:dataTable>
```

And the backing bean:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.mycompany.calendario;

@Named(value="vacDocBean")
@SessionScoped
public class VacDocBean implements Serializable {  

    private List<Vac> obl;

    public VacDocBean() {  

        obl = new ArrayList<Vac>();
        setVac();
        Collections.sort(obl);
    } 

    private void setVac()
    {
        this.obl = new ArrayList(Helper.getObl());
    }

    public List<Vac> getObl() {
        return obl;
    }

    public void setObligatorias(List<Vac> obl) {
        this.obl = obl;
    }

    public void onEditRow(RowEditEvent e){

        System.out.println("Hello");

    }

    public void onCancel(RowEditEvent e){

        System.out.println("Hello 2");

    }

}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Is your datatable surrounded by a `h:form` tag? Also remove your `update` attribute in `p:ajax`.

Comment: Yes!!  I added a h:form surrounding the datatable and it worked! Thanks! // I can't thumbs up for this comment because it isn't a response.

Comment: Added as a response. Glad to see it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just surround your `h:datatable` by a `h:form` tag, since the editable datatable needs it.

To make your listener method work, try that, whithout changing method's signature:

```
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{vacDocBean.onEditRow}" />
```

Comment: Ufff, and now I have not reputation enough to vote up. Sorry :( I still can't execute listener on backing bean, but edit mode switchs to normal mode when I click or check nor cross icon

Comment: There you have a solution, there's no need to vote the answer up, just click on the check ✓ when your problem is solved.

Comment: It doesn't work. I've tried with this signature and whit no parameters :S Thanks again. :)

Comment: Just follow [this convention](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowEditing.jsf).

Comment: It worked! I forgot uncomment the tags `<p:commandLink ajax="true">` and `</p:commandLink>` surrounding `<p:rowEditor/>`. Thanks a lot.